# Failed to compile play-services-places:15.0.1

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

Im not able to include  **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'** project. I'm getting the following error

```
  Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1. 

    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1.

    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1.

    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1.

     Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1. `
```

Note: If I remove **play-services-places:15.0.1** it works fine. The auth service works fine.

This is what I have.

**Project level gradle**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


 allprojects {  
 repositories {  
 google() 
 jcenter()  
 `maven { 
   url "https://maven.google.com"
  } 
 } 
}
```

**app gradle**

```
dependencies {


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1' 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

} 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you tried syncing by downgrading your lib version ?

Comment: No I have not. BTW I'm using firebase along with it is that a problem?

Comment: No that's not a problem sometimes it happens that the latest version of libraries doesn't work so by downgrading it start working. And one more thing try changing you library dependency to this  `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"`

Comment: Is offline-Mode enabled in your IDE?

Comment: yes offline mode is enabled

Comment: @Puni can you post your complete app.gradle file ?

Comment: @Christopher thanks, "offline-Mode"  that was the culprit. I uncheked and now its working.

Comment: @Umair thank you for the edit and helping with the problem I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question.

The solution was to disable **offline mode** from the comment by **Christopher**

Go to **Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle** and turn uncheck **Offline work**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have "Google Repository" installed in SDK manager? Also, beware of 2 separate SDK installations (One coming from Android Studio and one you might have downloaded separately).

[image]

Comment: I have "Google Repository" 58 same as yours already installed

Comment: Note, as of Aug 2017, the Google Repository SDK Manager entry is no longer updated; Google Play services is now available only via Google's Maven repository (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_version_1120)